# Ist it possible to automatically detect unused files in a drupal installation?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I had to adopt a very messy and hacky drupal based website.

Now I need to slowly weed out all the issues. Helpfully drupal seems to have a good cron script, which could clean up some things.

However there are tons of seemingly unused files (images, etc.).

Is there a way to search in the site which files are redundant?

Also, it seems that the administrator tried and used tons of now unused modules which left a lot of stuff in the database.

Any way to clean that up automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a way to remove unused files (non-module files).

However, if a module is no longer being used, you can [uninstall](http://drupal.org/node/250783) it via Disabling it at /admin/build/modules and Uninstalling at /admin/build/modules/uninstall.

Typically, most well-developed modules have a corresponding [hook_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21install.php/function/hook_uninstall/6) which should remove any variables and tables created by the module.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no script to clean up unused modules.
but you uninstall disabled module in one go using drush.
if your using drupal-6 make sure the module has hook_uninstall function to remove the table created by modules being uninstalled